Compare-Objects not returning the expected rows
I'm using Compare-Object to compare two arrays. The simplified versions are:
$dataFields : a list of all fields in our data models in our git Repo.
Dataset   Table             Field
-------   -----             -----
Sales     BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit

$reportFields : a list of all fields used in our Reports in production.
Workspace       Report              Dataset   Page                    Object       Type      Table             Field             
---------       ------              -------   ----                    ------       ----      -----             -----             
Sales           Invoices            Sales     Analysis                             Rows      BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
Sales           Customers           Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
Sales           Customers           Sales     Customer Insight                     Category  BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
Sales           Customers           Sales     Customer Analysis                    ExplainBy BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
Sales           Revenue             Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
Sales           Revenue             Sales     Analysis                             Rows      BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 
NewServices     Projects            Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit 


The point is to compare them to see if removing fields from our data models will affect any reports.
However, when I run:
$compareObjects = @{
    ReferenceObject  = $reportFields 
    DifferenceObject = $dataFields 
}

Compare-Object @compareObjects -Property Dataset, Table, Field -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Format-Table

I get the result below. Note that the only the first row from $reportFields is matched, while I would expect every row to match in this example.
Workspace       Report              Dataset   Page                    Object       Type      Table             Field        SideIndicator      
---------       ------              -------   ----                    ------       ----      -----             -----        -----           
Sales           Invoices            Sales     Analysis                             Rows      BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit == 
Sales           Customers           Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>
Sales           Customers           Sales     Customer Insight                     Category  BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>
Sales           Customers           Sales     Customer Analysis                    ExplainBy BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>
Sales           Revenue             Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>
Sales           Revenue             Sales     Analysis                             Rows      BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>
NewServices     Projects            Sales     ReportLevel             ReportFilter Filter    BusinessUnit      BusinessUnit =>


The cmdlet is indicating you that you have more objects on one side than in the other even tho their property values are the same. If you're just interested in knowing if the property values of the objects are the same on both sides then probably Compare-Object isn't the right cmdlet. you could just do: $reportFields | where { $_.Dataset -ne $reportFields.Dataset -or $_.Table -ne $reportFields.Table -or $_.Field -ne $reportFields.Field }

typo in my top comment : $reportFields | Where-Object { $_.Dataset -ne $dataFields.Dataset -or $_.Table -ne $dataFields.Table -or $_.Field -ne $dataFields.Field }

The arrays in my example were shortened but in reality they both have thousands of rows. So this approach wont work.
Besides combining -ne with -or will give a lot of false negatives. All 3 key fields need to be correct in order to have a match.

You basically need to find "all the lines in $ReportFields that match all the values in $DataFields", correct?

Just to let you know. You can do Union and Intersection too in PS directly and in your case , that would be more prudent.

As Santiago mentioned in comments, there are more objects in report fields than in data fields.  Compare-Object matches up objects 1-to-1 so you will only get one report field that shows '==' because there is only 1 object in data fields that can be matched.
To test the comparisons on your own a relatively efficient method can be to use hashtables
# create hashtables for each collection using Group-Object.  The keys will be strings 
# containing a concatenation of the properties (e.g. if using dataset, table, field 
# then "sales, businessunit, businessunit" would be an example of a key)
$reportFields_hash = $reportFields | Group-Object -Property dataset, table, field -AsHashTable -AsString 
$dataFields_hash = $dataFields | Group-Object -Property dataset, table, field -AsHashTable -AsString 

# @() will output all as a array.  I start with report fields on purpose 
# to ensure that all of the properties are shown in the resulting table 
# since format table will show only the properties available in the first object
@(
    # use GetEnumerator and ForEach-Object to iterate through all the 
    # key-value pairs  of both hashtables to ensure that a row from 
    # each colletion is in the output
    # (key = concatenated properties, value = collection of grouped objects)
    $reportFields_hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        # optionally add a field to indicate which collection 
        # the object is a part of (report vs data)
        $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'FieldType' -NotePropertyValue 'Report Field'
        if ($_.Key -in $dataFields_hash.Keys) {
            # check if key is also found in data field hashtable.  If so then equal
            $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SideIndicator' -NotePropertyValue '==' -PassThru
        }
        else {
            # otherwise we will indicate LHS
            $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SideIndicator' -NotePropertyValue '<=' -PassThru
        }
    }

    $dataFields_hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        # optionally add a field to indicate which collection 
        # the object is a part of (report vs data)
        $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'FieldType' -NotePropertyValue 'Data Field'
        if ($_.Key -in $reportFields_hash.Keys) {
            # check if key is also found in report field hashtable.  If so then equal
            $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SideIndicator' -NotePropertyValue '==' -PassThru
        }
        else {
            # otherwise we will indicate RHS
            $_.Value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SideIndicator' -NotePropertyValue '=>' -PassThru
        }
    }
) | Format-Table


Output
workspace   report    dataset  page              object       type     table        field        FieldType    SideIndicator
---------   ------    -------  ----              ------       ----     -----        -----        ---------    -------------
other       projects  products                                         product      client       Report Field <=
other       projects  sales                                            client       client       Report Field <=
sales       invoices  sales    analysis                       rows     businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
sales       customers sales    reportlevel       reportfilter filter   businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
sales       customers sales    customer insight               category businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
sales       customers sales    customer analysis              explain  businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
sales       revenue   sales    reportlevel       reportfilter filter   businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
sales       revenue   sales    analysis                       rows     businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
newservices projects  sales    reportlevel                    filter   businessunit businessunit Report Field ==
                      sales                                            businessunit businessunit Data Field   ==
                      notsales                                         client       client       Data Field   =>


